# Is it true that if $\pi: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is a dominant rational map, then for every representative $U \to Y$, the image is dense in $Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

> Definition: A rational map $\pi: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is dominant if for some (and hence every) representative $U \to Y$, the image is dense in $Y$.

I would like to show that if $\pi: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is a dominant rational map, then for every representative $U \to Y$, the image is dense in $Y$.

Let $\alpha: U \to Y$ be a representative such that $\overline{\alpha(U)}=Y$.

I have shown that if $\beta: V \to Y$ is in the same class as $\alpha$, then $\overline{\beta(V)} = Y$.

> This is because if $\alpha \sim \beta$, then there exists an open dense subset $Z \subset U \cap V$ such that $\alpha|_Z = \beta|_Z$. Now since the closure of $Z$ in $U$ is just $U$, i.e., $cl(Z,U)=U$, then, $Y=\overline{\alpha(U)}= \overline{\alpha(cl(Z,U))}=\overline{\alpha(Z)}=\overline{\beta(Z)}\subset \overline{\beta(V)}$.

However, I believe we still need to show that if $\beta: V \to Y$ is any other representative, then $\overline{\beta(V)} = Y$.

How do we go about this?

---

EDIT: Thanks to Daniel Apsley, I realized I was confused about the definition of *rational map*. For anyone confused about the definition, I think this is may help:

> Consider the set $$\{U \to Y \mid U \text{ is an open dense subset of } X, \text{ and } U\to Y \text{ is a morphism of schemes}\}.$$ Now, put an equivalence relation on this set via $(\alpha: U \to Y) \sim (\beta: V \to Y)$ if and only if there exists an open subset $Z \subset U\cap V$ which is dense in $X$ such that $\alpha|_Z = \beta|_Z$.

> A *rational map* is an equivalence class of this equivalence relation.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't $\beta$ another representative of $\alpha$ if and only if $\beta$ is in the same class as $\alpha$? If so, haven't you already shown this?

Comment: @DanielApsley $\beta$ is another representative of the rational map $\pi$. A rational map is an equivalence class of pairs $(U,f)$ where $U \subset X$ is an open dense subset of $X$ and $f: U \to Y$ is a morphism of schemes; where $(U,f) \sim (V,g)$ if and only if there exists an open dense set $Z \subset U \cap V$ such that $f|_Z = g|_Z$.

Comment: @DanielApsley Maybe I am misunderstanding the definition of rational map?

Comment: So you were able that if $\alpha$ is a dominant representative of $\pi$ and $\alpha \sim \beta$, then $\beta$ is also dominant, right? If $\beta$ is any representative of $\pi$, then $\alpha \sim \beta$ by the definition of an equivalence class.

Comment: @DanielApsley Given you're comment, I think I maybe misunderstood the definition of 'rational map'. Is it that we are considering the set $\{U \to Y \mid U \text{ is an open dense subset of } X, \text{ and } U\to Y \text{ is a morphism of schemes}\}$, and then we are putting said equivalence relation on this set and calling an equivalence class a 'rational map'?

Comment: As far as I am aware that is indeed the definition of a rational map.

Comment: @DanielApsley Thank you. I am glad I posted this question. I would've been very confused going forward if it were not for your comment.